# How can I extract an element from list and assign it to a variable (python)

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
data=[['link.com/fy6ocfid1gon'], ['link.com/9nvbmgarcou0'], ['link.com/23053636'], ['link.com/wn348oqec4jpm9'], ['link.com/P6Oj72a2rdI0ZVl'], ['link.com/1r0da0npo8mz'], ['link.com/fhe9tfkyl334']]
```

I want to extract `(fy6ocfid1gon)` and save it to a var.

I tried this:

```
var = data.replace('link.com/','')
print(var)
```

it doesn't work:

```
error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can try `print([a[0].split("/")[1] for a in data])`. But why is data 2D list to begin with?

Comment: it didn't work same error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
and for your question: I extracted data using BeautifulSoup from <li>

Comment: Your approach `data.replace()` is not working because `data` is a list, not a string. You need to access items inside data like `data[][]` to call replace on them

Comment: you are not running the code I added exactly as it is. My code is tested and working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the element from the list by indexing into the list and then use string slicing to remove the prefix 'link.com/':

```py
data = [
    ['link.com/fy6ocfid1gon'], 
    ['link.com/9nvbmgarcou0'],
    ['link.com/23053636'],
    ['link.com/wn348oqec4jpm9'],
    ['link.com/P6Oj72a2rdI0ZVl'],
    ['link.com/1r0da0npo8mz'],
    ['link.com/fhe9tfkyl334']
]

var = data[0][0].replace('link.com/', '')
print(var)
```

- data[0][0] accesses the first element of the list (which is itself a list)
- .replace('link.com/', '') removes the 'link.com/' prefix from the string
- The result is saved into var

So this will extract 'fy6ocfid1gon' from the list and save it to var.

**To extract the id from every element in the list, you can loop through the list:**

```py
data = [
    ['link.com/fy6ocfid1gon'],
    ['link.com/9nvbmgarcou0'], 
    ['link.com/23053636'],
    ['link.com/wn348oqec4jpm9'],
    ['link.com/P6Oj72a2rdI0ZVl'],
    ['link.com/1r0da0npo8mz'],
    ['link.com/fhe9tfkyl334'] 
]

ids = []
for item in data:
    id = item[0].replace('link.com/', '')
    ids.append(id)

print(ids)
```

1. Loop through each item in the data list
2. For each item, extract the id using .replace(), same as before
3. Append the id to a new list ids
4. After the loop, ids will contain all the extracted ids

This allows you to extract the id from every element in the list into a new list.